# When one activity makes you less distracted doing another activity?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, terminology, performance, motivation

**Background:** When I'm coding, I sometimes make tea, and as long as I'm drinking the tea, I find myself more focused. Drinking tea seems to make me focus more. Thus, it seems that while doing something else I am less likely to be distracted. Another example that seems similar is listening to music while working out (running for example).

#### Question

- Is there a term that describes the process by which engaging in a small secondary task increases focus on the primary task?
- Are the two examples of drinking tea while coding and listening to music while working out related?

Comment: as is, i think this question is too broad. yes, 'things' can help people focus on other 'things'. in the psych literature, it's called attention. it's worth noting that caffeine (in tea) can cause increased attention. so perhaps that plays a role in your case. (in fact, this may be a viable question if you limit this to possible effects of tea on attention)

Comment: @Roronoa Zoro: I know exactly what you are referring to as I experience it. It has to do with overriding focus, this question slightly touches yours, may want to take a look. :http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1296/what-is-the-scientific-term-or-concept-for-inner-thought-control